# Firewall level request duplication

Tags: iis, iis-7, firewall, request

I'm trying to duplicate incoming HTTP requests such that one copy goes to an IIS server that will serve responses back to the client while the other copy goes to another server for further processing and offline research purposes.  Both servers are behind a firewall.  I know it's possible to generate a duplicate request event once a request has reached IIS, but is it possible to duplicate requests using the firewall that receives requests before they are forwarded to IIS?

Thanks in advance for your help,

-Eric

Comment: What kind of firewall is sitting in front of your servers?

Comment: Checkpoint firewalls are sitting in front of our servers.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux firewall(iptables):

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TEE --gateway IP
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to finagle some of this data with a [mirrored switch port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_mirroring).